# I want to apply filter: blur to any shape

Tags: javascript

Click on the image to hit the path.
Click the first point after hitting three or more passes to close the pass.
When the path is closed, I want to select the inside of the path and implement the function to blur the range.
Currently, nothing happens when you close the path.

Comment: I have voted to close this as too broad following your edit which removed all of the important parts / code from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mistaken about `Paper.js` rendering engine.
It draws its items in the context of a `<canvas>` element, so all you will be able to access from developer tool is this canvas and its image data.
You will not be able to target your path and act on it using selectors which seems to be what you are trying to do.

Anyway, unfortunately, `Paper.js` doesn't currently support filters.
So one option could be to take advantage of the canvas context [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property (experimental) or to implement the blurring algorithm yourself.
Then, while keeping `Paper.js` utility for drawing, you could manage multiple canvases and do smart compositing to produce the effect that you are looking for.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16bf4nuq/) demonstrating a possible implementation.
Note that for the sake of the demo, I simplified your use case but you should be able to adapt it to your case quite easily.
In this example, I use 3 different canvases:
- the bottom one is for drawing the original image
- the middle one is for drawing the blurred part
- the top one is for drawing the shape that we will use for compositing and will be hidden at the end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug Paper.js</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-core.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin   : 0;
            overflow : hidden;
            height   : 100%;
        }

        /* We position canvases on top of each other. */
        canvas {
            position : absolute;
            top      : 0;
            left     : 0;
            width    : 100vw;
            height   : 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="bottom-canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="middle-canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="top-canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    // Get canvases references.
    const bottomCanvas = document.getElementById('bottom-canvas');
    const middleCanvas = document.getElementById('middle-canvas');
    const topCanvas = document.getElementById('top-canvas');

    // Initialise 2 PaperScopes.
    const bottomScope = new paper.PaperScope();
    bottomScope.setup(bottomCanvas);
    const topScope = new paper.PaperScope();
    topScope.setup(topCanvas);

    // For middle canvas, we need to adjust the size manually as Paper.js doesn't handle it.
    middleCanvas.width = middleCanvas.offsetWidth;
    middleCanvas.height = middleCanvas.offsetHeight;

    // Draw the image on the bottom canvas.
    new paper.Raster({
        source: 'https://i.imgur.com/6N0Zwag.jpg',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        position: bottomScope.view.center,
        parent: bottomScope.project.activeLayer,
        // When image is loaded...
        onLoad: function() {
            // ...make it fit the whole canvas.
            this.fitBounds(bottomScope.view.bounds, true);

            // Draw a circle on the top canvas that represents the user drawn shape
            // that we want to use for blurring.
            new paper.Path.Circle({
                center: topScope.view.center,
                radius: 200,
                fillColor: 'orange',
                parent: topScope.project.activeLayer
            });

            // We manually call the canvas view update to make sure that everything
            // is drawn before we play with image data.
            bottomScope.view.update();
            topScope.view.update();

            // Get middle canvas context to be able to draw on it.
            const middleCanvasContext = middleCanvas.getContext('2d');
            // Draw the bottom canvas image on the middle canvas with the blur filter applied.
            middleCanvasContext.filter = 'blur(15px)';
            middleCanvasContext.drawImage(bottomCanvas, 0, 0);

            // In order to see the clear part of the bottom canvas image,
            // we need to remove from middle canvas what is not on top canvas.
            // For that, we use "destination-in" composite operation.
            middleCanvasContext.filter = 'none';
            middleCanvasContext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
            middleCanvasContext.drawImage(topCanvas, 0, 0);

            // Now, we need to hide the top canvas, to see the middle one below it.
            topCanvas.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```